# How to select a dynamic ID dropdown list c#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver to develop a UI automation project.
At one page I have a dynamic element in a dropdown list.

This is an example of the Xpath found with selenium IDE:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='ui-id-89']/strong")).Text);
```

The ID is dynamic,in this example the number **89**. I tryed to use:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@id,'ui-id']"))
```

and

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("*[id^='ui-id'][id$='> strong']"))
```

Nothing worked, anyone have a solution to help me?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="main" role="main">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Extrato Financeiro</h2>
      <p></p>
      <form method="post" class="search jNice" id="form-filter" name="form-filter" action="">
        <fieldset >
          <label  for='labelcmbCodPeriodoLetivo'  id='labelcmbCodPeriodoLetivo'   name="labelcmbCodPeriodoLetivo"  dev-comp="true"  dev-id='labelcmbCodPeriodoLetivo'   value="Período Letivo"  dev-event=""  dev-action="" >Período Letivo</label >
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset >
          <select  id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo'   name="cmbCodPeriodoLetivo"  dev-comp="true"  dev-id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo'   value="2801"  dev-height='38px'   dev-width='4'   dev-height='38px'   dev-event=""  dev-action="" text-sel="Selecione" dev-select-link="" dev-select-codigo=""  dev-select-param='' >
            <option value=' ' id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt_sel0' > Selecione </option>
            <option value=' ' id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt_sel1'> ---------------- </option>
            <option value='{"SGLPERIODOLETIVO":"2017\/1","CODPERIODOLETIVO":"2801"}'  selected  id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt0'   name="cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt0"  dev-comp="true"  dev-id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt0'   dev-event=""  dev-action="">2017/1</option> 
            <option value='{"SGLPERIODOLETIVO":"2016\/2","CODPERIODOLETIVO":"2713"}'  id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt1'   name="cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt1"  dev-comp="true"  dev-id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt1'   dev-event=""  dev-action="">2016/2</option> 
            <option value='{"SGLPERIODOLETIVO":"2016\/1","CODPERIODOLETIVO":"2616"}'  id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt2'   name="cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt2"  dev-comp="true"  dev-id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt2'   dev-event=""  dev-action="">2016/1</option> 
            <option value='{"SGLPERIODOLETIVO":"2015\/2","CODPERIODOLETIVO":"2396"}'  id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt3'   name="cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt3"  dev-comp="true"  dev-id='cmbCodPeriodoLetivo_opt3'   dev-event=""  dev-action="">2015/2</option>     
          </select>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Comment: Please share the html

Comment: @Guy shared in the post.

Comment: there is no ui-id in this html

Comment: Using the selenium IDE send me only 2 options showed in this post.

Comment: In the html you provided there is no id with `id='ui-id'`, and no `<a>` and `<strong>` tags. Please share the correct code and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Select method here.

```
Select oSelect = new     Select(driver.findElement(By.id("labelcmbCodPeriodoLetivo")));
oSelect.selectByVisibleText("2016/2");
```

OR

you can go ahead and list the elements in dropdown

```
List<WebElement> elem = oSelect.getOptions();
        int iSize = elem.size();
        System.out.println("Size of the list is" +iSize);

        for(int i=0; i <iSize;i++)
        {
            String sValue = oSelect.getOptions().get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(sValue);

            if(sValue.equals("2016/2"))
            {
                System.out.println("Position of the value is" +i);
                oSelect.selectByIndex(i);


                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @SaymonCAO np! will you be accepting the answer? Appreciate it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i used this sequence of code to do something in the component:

1. Clear the field;
2. SendKey in the field;
3. Click on the first result in the dropdown element;

Here is the source code of my solution:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='form-filter']/fieldset[2]/span[2]/input")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='form-filter']/fieldset[2]/span[2]/input")).SendKeys(Input String);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body/ul/li/a")).Click();
```

Thanks for all the answers.